# What does the standard (HTML5 and EcmaScript 5.1) say about extending host objects in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-5

What do the recent standards say about extending host objects and their prototypes? E.g. is extending `NodeList` with a method `_forEach` or `Document` with a method `_my_query` properly defined?

Will I see anything I add to `Object.prototype` on host objects by the standard?

How do real implementations behave with respect to the relevant standards?

Note: I am not asking whether it is a good idea to extend host objects or their prototypes (although `Object.defineProperty` makes things a bit easier when it comes to enumerating issues).

Comment: should work in IE9+. Object.prototype mods should show up on host objects, but it would be better to use Node.prototype or Element.prototype or HTMLCollection.prototype, etc....

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 5 does not say anything about host objects' prototype chain.

This is defined in **[WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/)**.

Specifically, take a look at [ECMAScript bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/#ecmascript-binding) section, which says:

> Unless otherwise specified, the [[Prototype]] internal property of
>   objects defined in this section is the Object prototype object.

and this, from [the following section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/#es-environment):

> Each ECMAScript global environment ([ECMA-262], section 10.2.3) must
>   have its own unique set of each of the initial objects, created before
>   control enters any ECMAScript execution context associated with the
>   environment, but after the global object for that environment is
>   created. The [[Prototype]]s of all initial objects in a given global
>   environment must come from that same global environment.

There's even [an example](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/#es-environment):

```
iframe.appendChild instanceof Function;    // Evaluates to true
```

Finally, [Interface Prototype Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/#interface-prototype-object) section says (emphasis mine):

> The named properties object for a given interface A must have an
>   internal [[Prototype]] property whose value is as follows:
>
> If A is not declared to inherit from another interface, then the value
>   of the internal [[Prototype]] property of A is the Array prototype
>   object ([ECMA-262], section 15.4.4) if the interface was declared with
>   [ArrayClass], **or the Object prototype object otherwise**
>   ([ECMA-262], section 15.2.4).
>
> Otherwise, A does inherit from another interface. The value of the
>   internal [[Prototype]] property of A is the interface prototype object
>   for the inherited interface.

So now if we look at DOM Level 3, and [Document interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document) we can see that it inherits from Node interface. Node interface does not explicitly inherit from anything else, which means it inherits from `Object.prototype`.

This is theory :)

In practice, not all browsers follow this behavior, although most of the recent ones certainly do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing again at the fact that prototypes are different for different ECMAScript execution contexts.

Does WebIDL imply that the browser scripting environment has to expose `NodeList` or `HTMLElement` or that it is only guaranteed that they are accessible via `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('div'))`, etc.?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes. In [4.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-WebIDL-20120419/#es-interfaces) it says: "For every interface that: ... a __corresponding property must exist on the ECMAScript global object__. The name of the property is the identifier of the interface, and its value is an object called the interface object."

Comment: btw, you can also see mention of NamedConstructors in that same section. And an example of Interface having different constructor name (i.e. NamedConstructor) — `[NamedConstructor=Audio, NamedConstructor=Audio(DOMString src)]
interface HTMLAudioElement`

Answer (score 1):

The ECMASCRIPT5 spec states :

> A web server provides a different host environment for server-side
>   computation including objects representing requests, clients, and
>   files; and mechanisms to lock and share data. By using browser-side
>   and server-side scripting together, it is possible to distribute
>   computation between the client and server while providing a customised
>   user interface for a Web-based application.
>
> Each Web browser and server that supports ECMAScript supplies its own host environment,
>   completing the ECMAScript execution environment.

I do not think it says anything else. This can be read to mean that an implementation can conform to the spec and implement the browser objects however it wants. This has been the case in the past. It does seem logical though to apply the power of the language to the external environment and I believe that all "modern" browsers now do that.

Comment: This leaves open whether the HTML5 or DOM specs define how the host environment should behave; in particular which host objects and prototypes are there. At least, your quote opens up all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

the dom/html elements have an prototype chain as follows:
`HTMLElement > Element > Node > Object`
hooking in anywhere in the chain where it makes the senes is probly the best bet.

Comment: This does not address the OP question of what the specification actually says.